# Automatically Copying Excel file in same directory and same file name

Tags: c#, sql, excel, winforms

I tried import a Excel file using c#. When I tried to import a Excel file is creating a new Excel file with same name of importing file also that new file is corrupted. I don't why this happened. 
My code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //database name
        string table = "importing";
        // Excel sheet name
        string excelQuery = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
        try
        {
            //create  connection strings
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\New folder (2)\\importing1.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
            string sqlConnectionstring = "Data Source=LAB-2\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LMS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=smart;Password=smart";
            //To clear the previous data in the database
            string resetQuery = "delete from " + table;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionstring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(resetQuery, connection);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            //copy data from the excel file 
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmdOLEDB = new OleDbCommand(excelQuery, con);
             con.Open();
             OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionstring);
            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = table;
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }          
    }
```